# Flutter web Image.network rotates image

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, web, orientation

I have the problem, that Image.network shows an Image rotated in the webapp. But if I open the same url in a browser, the orientation is correct.

[In my webap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m5vo.jpg)

[In the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Hjo.jpg)

Can somebody help me?

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'dart:js' as js;

class NetworkImageError extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NetworkImageErrorState createState() => _NetworkImageErrorState();
}

class _NetworkImageErrorState extends State<NetworkImageError> {
  String DownloadUrl='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Placeholder_no_text.svg'; //Placeholder

  GetURL()async{
    var _DownloadURL = await fb
        .storage()
        .refFromURL('gs://myBucket')
        .child('Pb_0000.png')
        .getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      DownloadUrl=_DownloadURL.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    GetURL();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              js.context.callMethod("open", [DownloadUrl]);
            },
            child: Image.network(DownloadUrl)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Transform widget
import 'dart:math' as math;

then

```
Transform(
alignment: Alignment.center,
transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
child: Image.network( "url", scale: 8, alignment: Alignment.center)
)
```

Comment: This is not working.